# Maximum value determination

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $a, b, c \;\text{and}\; d$ be different positive integers, and it is known that $a+b+c+d+e=20$. What is the maximum value of $a·b+c·d+e$?

Can someone give an answer and the steps to answer it? I'm still studying here, please help

Comment: is $e$ also a positive integer different from the others?

Comment: It could be different or the same sir

Comment: So $a, b, c, d$ are distinct positive integers, and $e$ is just a positive integer with no requirement that it is distinct? Can any of the integers be $0$?

Comment: But still a positive integer? Or aren't there any restrictions for $e$?

Comment: Well, itu doesn't say. But let e be a positive integer too

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I could get 74 by doing a = 9, b = 8, c = 2 d = 1 and e = 0. I could get more, but I need to make either a, b, c, or d a zero, is zero considered a positive integer?

Comment: @Godlixe $0$ being positive may depend on where in the world the author of the problem grew up. I would say it's not, but a French person might say it is. (At least I heard a French person say once that that was what he learned in school.)

Comment: Well, the I don't know anything about the author still. It's just a question from some test papers I found. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it :). But is my answer correct yet? If anyone has a different answer feel free to correct mine, thanks ><